# How to send bulk email with timer?

Tags: php, email, newsletter

Let's say I have 200 users in my database and currently host on shared hosting. I want to send a newsletter to them and send only 10 emails every 5 minutes.

I'll send the newsletter using [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). Questions..

- What is the good concept to send a newsletter using existing database without export it to 3rd party services?
- What is the key to make sure script will not send duplicate newsletter in same time?
- What is the good practice to achieve my goal.

Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a task to select a fixed number of un-sent newsletters from the database (I would either delete sent newsletters or mark them as sent, or move them to another table). In your case you're obviously wanting to send 10 every 5 minutes, so set the task to fetch 10 emails, and send them. Then set up a cron and have it run every five minutes... There's probably a more elegant solution though if you're only ever planning on sending out the emails once / twice a week. You could do some while loops with a sleep command but thats not particularly resource efficient.... I would just go with the above - its probably the most flexible brute force solution, and your host won't really notice as it'll still be relatively quick.

Answer (score 3):

You should just use a 3d party service with a good API. It will be much less work in the long run.

You haven't thought about bounce handling, unsubscribe, domain keys, avoiding blacklists and more.

At best your messages will end up in the junk mail box.

At worse your IP will be banned and your account terminated for sending unsolicted email (Your ISP won't care if they actually signed up for it).

Comment: I agree, but for a database of just 200 users? I'd just go for the cheap and easy for now and scale up if needed later on....

Comment: There is no cheap&easy for manual implementation of newsletters imo. +1 for using ready made solutions.

Comment: If I moved to dedicated server the problem will be same?

Comment: If I export current email to 3rd service like Aweber, user must verify again their email address..

Comment: You always have to realistically assess if you're knocking in a nail with a sledge-hammer. If it's a simple plain-text / basic html email, sent out on a weekly basis, to about 200 users - there's no real need to integrate with an API (just now). Better to code a quick and nasty solution and get the job done for now. As soon as the userbase / frequency scales up though - it'll be time to look at using a 3rd party.